# Por que XAMPP abre multiples puertos aun estado configurado

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, tomcat, puertos

tengo xampp, instalado en Windows Server 2008, ya configure los puertos manualmente, pero hay momento en xampp empieza a ejecutar y abre mútiples puertos, desencadenando haciendo que el que el servidor se cuelgue, quisiera saber a qué se debe este problema, y qué provoca que se abran tantos puertos cada vez que un usuario hace un movimiento en las computadoras clientes les agradesco me ayuden

Comment: Resolviste tú problema? estoy en la misma situación. Saludos,

Comment: ¿Como qué número de puertos abre? ¿Notas algo raro en access.log? ¿El servidor tiene IP pública y es alcanzable desde internet?

Comment: yo resolvi mi problematica el problema refleja en que si tienes truncada la base de datos (errores) toca repararla, igual l codigo php puede que tengas errores de peticion a las tablas de la base de datos fijense de que todo este bien indexado tanto las peticiones a la DB y que el codigo PHP este bien programado mas que todo en la sentencias SQL saludos